# How to create 'Horizontal style' progress bar programmatically in Android?

Tags: android, android-progressbar, android-styles

I am creating a ProgressBar in my app programmatically it is of SPIN style by default however I want it in HORIZONTAL style. I don't see any method/constant to achieve this.

And I don't want to use ProgressDialog as it'd be inconsistent with my App UI theme.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: you haven't read this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Comment: that explains ProgressDialog while I am appending ProgressBar directly in my view. It appears but not in Horizontal style. Please correct me if I missed anything in the link you suggested.

Comment: I think there is something titled under **"Showing a progress bar"** can help you.

Comment: that article explains about ProgressDialog but not ProgressBar

Answer (score 93, accepted):

use this:

```
ProgressBar pb = new ProgressBar(context,
                                 null, 
                                 android.R.attr.progressBarStyleHorizontal);
```

Comment: this works when we initialize it. How can we do it afterwards? How can we change the style online?

Comment: you cannot change view's `Style` once it is initialized.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a ProgressDialog then, here is a way to change the style of the progressBar in the ProgressDialog.

```
mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
```